# Singular form of verb for noncount words

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I learnt a rule from my grammar notebook:

> Always use the singular form of a verb for noncount (uncountable) words:
>
> Where **is** my money?
>
> There **is** some rice on the table.

But I recalled a sentence that does not follow this rule:

> The police **are** on their way.

And also another one:

> These fish **are** poisonous.

So why does the rule break here?

Comment: They're not uncountable nouns. *The police* is something referred to as a collective noun and *fish* is a noun whose plural form is formed irregularly.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRybkin for answering, is there a list that seperates these words where I can study and memorize all of them? Also is there any other type of nouns that does not follow THE rule?

Comment: Do a web search for "English collective nouns" and "irregular nouns" and then follow the links that you get.

Comment: Erm. I thought these are uncommon things but I found a lot of results..! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, [police is a collective noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/matching-verbs-to-collective-nouns) which takes a plural verb.

In your other sentence, *fish* is the plural of *fish*, the aquatic creature. Its plural is different than that of regular nouns.